# In Postgres, find out if a value in one row exists as a value in another row, but two different columns

Tags: postgresql

I had to create a secondary table to be able to compare them, like so:

```
WHERE EXISTS  

(SELECT *

    FROM db."fTable2"  

    WHERE (db."fTable2"."idParent" = db."fTable1"."idWit"))
```

Both idParent and idWit exists in Table1, but comparing both in the same table resulted in nothing, while creating a secondary table fTable2 did the job.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: How is your Table1 defined? Please [edit] your question to include its schema. Also add an example of the data in it and the result that the query should have for it.

Comment: "*I had to create a secondary table to be able to compare them*" - it's not clear at all how you did that and what the query is doing now. What data is in that secondary table? What was the problem with the original query that used only one table? Please include the full code of that non-working query as well.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you had something like this: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/wbrhISme)

```sql
create schema db;
create table db."fTable1" (
  "idParent" int, 
  "idWit" int);
insert into db."fTable1" values 
(11,21),
(12,22),
(13,23),
(14,11),--this one's "idWit" matches the first row's "idParent"
(15,25);
```

Did something along the lines of:

```sql
select * from db."fTable1" where db."fTable1"."idParent"=db."fTable1"."idWit";
```

But that checked `"idParent"` and `"idWit"` from the exact same row, so it found nothing. So you did something like this:

```sql
select * 
from db."fTable1"
where exists (
  select * 
  from db."fTable1"
  where (db."fTable1"."idParent" = db."fTable1"."idWit"));
```

But that again found nothing, because the subquery in `exists` is checking the exact same thing: whether there's a row where within that one row, these two values are the same. So you took them out to another table:

```sql
create table db."fTable2" as table db."fTable1";
```

And now it works, because it's now taking rows from `db."fTable1"` and looking for matching rows in `db."fTable2"`. Thing is, you could've aliased `db."fTable1"` to state explicitly you're referring to the same table twice, without having to clone it:

```sql
select * 
from db."fTable1" as t1
where exists (
  select * 
  from db."fTable1" as t2
  where t2."idParent"=t1."idWit"); --acts as if it was a whole other table now
```

Or, as @[Kaushik Narayan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7630441/kaushik-narayan) [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75893126/5298879), you could [`join`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-join.html) the table with itself:

```sql
select * 
from db."fTable1" as t1 
inner join db."fTable1" as t2
on t2."idParent"=t1."idWit";
```

That's a ton of guessing. You'd get clearer answers, quicker, if you showed your `create table` statement, the code you actually tried, the results or errors you were getting and what you expected instead.

Comment: +1                                                                                           for clearly stating all the guesses you made

Answer (score -1):

```sql
SELECT * FROM db."fTable2" INNER JOIN db."fTable1" ON db."fTable2"."idParent" = db."fTable1"."idWit"
```

[`JOINs`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)) are what you need.

Comment: This is neither necessarily the same, nor necessarily any simpler. It selects more columns and more rows than the OPs query. Maybe a good idea, but not "needed". We can't tell from the question.